# How to indicate that an Android app only supports ARM CPUs?

Tags: android, arm, cpu-architecture

I have an Android application that only runs on ARM CPUs. This is due to the fact that I have included an ARM executable in the APK. However, after quite a bit of searching, I have been unable to find any way to indicate (in a manifest file or something similar) that the application *will not run* on other architectures.

Normally, applications that want to include native code include a shared library. In this case, the app only shows up in the Play Store for users with a compatible CPU. However, using a shared library is not an option for my app.

Is there some place in the project's manifest file or somewhere else that I can explicitly indicate the CPU architectures the app supports?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/google/play/filters.html#other-filters :
_An application that includes native libraries that target a specific CPU architecture [..] are visible only on devices that support that architecture._  

I don't have a Google-Developer-Account yet, but maybe you can add filters when publishing your app in the playstore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, using a shared library is not an option for my app.

In theory, it should be. Create a do-nothing little JNI-compatible library with the NDK, and only build it for architectures that your packaged-in binary supports (e.g., ARMv5 and ARMv7). You probably don't even have to use the library (though I'd set up a Java class that references it to be safe, at least during initial testing). That *should* be enough to trigger Play Store filters, even if you never actually invoke the code at runtime.

IOW, use the NDK stuff just for filtering.

Personally, I'd rewrite your command-line binary to be a NDK-built JNI-compatible library, for performance reasons, but that's just me.

Comment: Hey - now that's clever! Great idea!

Comment: @NathanOsman: One way to test this theory is to see if the Motorola RAZR i is listed as a supported device once you make this change, as that's the one x86-based handset that I can think of that definitely supports the Play Store.

Answer (score 0):

This is may be what you are looking for

```
TextView tv_showArch_View = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.ShowCPUArch);
        String CPU_ABI = Build.CPU_ABI;

        tv_showArch_View.setText(CPU_ABI);
```

It returned to me

`ARMeabi`   for Emulator running on `ARM processor`

and

`X86` for Emulator running on `Intel processor`

For More detailed information you can go thru [Google's Official Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html)

Comment: Yes, but this doesn't prevent the app from being displayed in the Play Store to users with x86 or MIPS CPUs.